Azure function app in python not trigger when blob is uploaded
I have a consumption based function app in python which will be triggered when a blob with extension .db is created/uploaded in a folder in a container of a storage account.
function.json:
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
   {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "abc360/sqlite_db_file/{name}.db",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
   }
  ]
}

local.settings.json:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
   "AzureWebJobsStorage": "connection string",
   "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python"
  }
}

This is my settings in visual studio code.
I have created a build and release pipeline for deploying function app to azure. It works fine and updates the code in cloud.
But for some reason, when a db file is uploaded, function app is not triggered. It works locally.
Which confirms there is some setting in cloud that i fuzzed up.
Please help me get this right.
Thank You!

Have you added your AzureWebJobsStorage with connection string in the function app environment variables in Azure Portal?

@DasariKamali Yes. It is present in function app's configuration section with storage accounts connection string.

I can able to upload the blob. You can see this in this Monitor logs.

Before going to deploy the project to the Function app, I have added the connection string to the function app's Environment variables.

I have updated my answer with local.settings.json and function.json.

As mentioned, I added the kam11funcstr_STORAGE in my Function app> Environment variables.

Can you fix the issue while updating the above connection string in the Function app > Environment variables?

@DasariKamali I did all of the above, still doesn't work.

Did you get any errors while running the code in the Function app and uploading the blob?

@DasariKamali no error.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I successfully triggered the blob trigger function in the Function App within the Azure portal.
As mentioned in the local.settings.json and function.json, I used the storage connection string in kam11funcstr_STORAGE (you can set any name here). This connection should be passed in the Function App > Environment variables.
local.settings.json :
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<storage_conne>",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "kam11funcstr_STORAGE": "<storage_conne>"
  }
}

function.json :
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "abc360/sqlite_db_file/{name}.db",
      "connection": "kam11funcstr_STORAGE"
    }
  ]
}

Note : -
Before deploying the code to the Azure Function App, you need to add the connection as shown below in the Function App > Environment variables.
kam11funcstr_STORAGE = <storage_conne_styring>


After successful deployment, I ran the function code in the Azure Function App and uploaded the .db file to Azure Blob Storage as follows:

Azure Portal :
The blob trigger function ran successfully as shown below:

The blob trigger function successfully triggered, as shown in the Function App's Monitor logs below.


Environment variables is to be added  in Application Settings or Connection Strings in portal ?

@RahulSharma Should be added to Environment variables > App Settings. You can check in the Screenshot, I shared in my answer.

images aren't coming through.

I monitored app via insight and found there is an exception:
Exception while executing function: Functions.Generate_Csv_From_Db_File <--- Result: Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.storage'. Cannot find module. Please check the requirements.txt file for the missing module. For more info, please refer the troubleshooting guide: https://aka.ms/functions-modulenotfound. Current sys.path: ['/tmp/functions\standby\wwwroot'.
Dont understand why this is happening.

@Rahul Sharma Have you added the azure-storage-blob package in your requirements.txt file locally? Have you installed it using pip install -r requirements.txt?

Yes.
azure-core==1.30.1
azure-functions==1.18.0
azure-storage-blob==12.19.1
certifi==2024.2.2
cffi==1.16.0
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
cryptography==42.0.5
idna==3.6
isodate==0.6.1
pycparser==2.21
requests==2.31.0
six==1.16.0
typing_extensions==4.10.0
urllib3==2.2.1
This is my requirements.txt file.

In build pipeline, I use this for installing dependency:
python3.8 -m venv worker_venv
source worker_venv/bin/activate
pip3.8 install setuptools
pip3.8 install --target="$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r "function app/requirements.txt"
I dont know where I am going wrong.

@Rhul Sharma If possible can you share your GitHub repo or your code in the question?
And can you let me know how you build the pipeline?

since its customer repository, cant do that. Can we please connect ? Need to get this sorted. You have amazing understanding about this.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
